# More info needed on number of nodes generated by Breadth First Search

Tags: graph, tree, artificial-intelligence, breadth-first-search

I am new to AI and was going through Peter Norvig book. I've looked into this question already [What is the number of nodes generated by breadth-first search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990358/what-is-the-number-of-nodes-generated-by-breadth-first-search/16270317#16270317).
It says that if we apply goal test to each node when it is selected for expansion then we have nodes = **1 + b + b^2 + b^3 + ... + b^d + (b^(d+1) - b)**
But what if my goal state is a leaf node at the final depth. So there is no depth at all after the goal. Then how can b^(d+1) evaluate?. eg: in a tree with max depth 3, if my goal lies at depth 3, then how would I evaluate b^(3+1) when there is no 4th level at all?. Please clear my doubt. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the answer you linked mentioned that that is the amount of nodes that will be **generated** in the **worst case**.

**Generated** means that not all of those nodes are tested to see if they are the goal; they're simply generated and stored so that they can eventually be compared to the goal in case the goal is not found yet.

**Worst case** has two important implications. Try to visualize the Breadth-First Search going from left to right, then down one level, then left to right again, then down, etc. With worst case we assume that, on whatever depth level *d* the goal is located, the goal is the very last (rightmost) node. This means that all nodes to the left of it are compared to the goal node, and any successors/children of them are generated as well.

Now, I know that you said that in **your case** there are no nodes at a depth level below *d*, but the second implication of saying **worst case** is that we do assume there are basically infinitely many depth levels.

Indeed, for **your case** that equation is not entirely correct, but this is simply because you don't have the **worst case**. In your case, the search process would indeed not have to generate the last **(b^(d+1) - b)** nodes of the equation.

A final note on the terminology you used: you asked how **b^(d+1)** (for example, **b^(3+1)** can be evaluated if there is no depth level below **d = 3**. There is still no problem to mathematically evaluate that term. Even in your case there is no depth level 4, we can still mathematically evaluate the term **b^(3+1)**. In your case it would not make sense to do so, because it is not correct, but we can still evaluate the term just fine.

Comment: Thanks Dennis for a detailed explanation . As you mentioned, we are assuming infinite depth, then it completely makes sense. Thanks a lot